# How to get original sender of a forwarded email with Outlook interop?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, office-2010, outlook-2010

I'm developing an add in for Outlook 2010 and I need to be able to retrieve the sender's email address for a MailItem or the email address of the original sender if it is a a forwarded email. Is there any easy way to do that second one besides parsing through the body of the email?

Answer (score 1):

Use OutlookSpy and see if there is any MAPI property exposed that gives you the data you are looking for.

Download it from here
http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/

Comment: I dont think there is any such property though. You may have to do the custom parsing of the mail body (considering that user didn't temper the body)